# 'LSTM' object has no attribute '_flat_weights_names'

Tags: python, pytorch, nltk, torch

While executing iNltk library, I am getting an error. I have latest versions of pytorch and torchvision.

```
'LSTM' object has no attribute '_flat_weights_names'
```

After re-searching on some blogs some people suggested to downgrade the version to 1.2 So i tried below installation from https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

```
pip install torch==1.2.0+cu92 torchvision==0.4.0+cu92 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

However, getting errors

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.2.0+cpu
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.2.0+cpu
```

Also, 1.3.1 version is missing.

Anybody has any idea about how to downgrade to 1.3.1 or 1.2.0?

Thanks in advance

PD

Answer (score 2):

I tried using `pip`, but that did not work for me. `conda` fixed the issue.

Setup a `conda` environment first and activate it. Install `iNLTK` using `pip` in `conda` as follows:

```
pip install inltk
```

Remove the version of PyTorch installed as a dependency for `iNLTK`.

```
pip uninstall torch
```

Install the desired version of PyTorch.

```
conda install pytorch==1.3.0 -c pytorch
```

Refer: [Previous PyTorch Versions](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/)

Answer (score 1):

In google colaboratory,I got the same error while executing iNltk library.
In Inltk Installation (https://inltk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_docs.html)
they have provided as:

!pip install torch==1.3.1+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

!pip install inltk

but the **actual order of implementation** is:

!pip install inltk

!pip install torch==1.3.1+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html.

So by reversing order of execution of installation,solved error as the torch version gets corrected by following this order.